# Create .xml and .pdb files from .dll file

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0

I have a .dll file from a Silverlight class library. How can I create a .pdb and a .xml file from this .dll file?

Comment: That's not possible. The only thing that may be interesting to you is [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. Whoever supplies the DLL must supply the auxiliary files too.

Answer (score 0):

And if you have the source code you can generate them on your own by making sure you build as debug rather than retail/free.

Why do you want them?